# How to get revision dates for first and last update for multiple objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-simple-history

I need to make a bulk query for all instances of SomeModel, annotating them with the date of their creation and last update. Here's what I tried and is terribly slow:

```
query = SomeModel.objects.all()
for entry in query:
    last_updated_date = entry.details.history.last().history_date
    created_date = entry.details.history.first().history_date
    csv_writer.writerow([entry.name, last_updated_date, created_date])
```

How could I optimize the code? I imagine that the problem is that I'm making a lot of SELECT queries, when probably a single bit more complex one would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this(using [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

histories = HistoricalRecords.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('details__history')).order_by('history_date')

SomeModel.objects.annotate(created_date=Subquery(histories.values('history_date')[:1])).annotate(last_updated==Subquery(histories.order_by('-history_date').values('history_date')[:1]))
```

FYI: this is an untested code.